# Scala array initialization

Tags: arrays, scala, initialization

You have:

```
val array = new Array[Array[Cell]](height, width)
```

How do you initialize all elements to new Cell("something")?

Thanks,
Etam (new to Scala).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
val array = Array.fill(height)(Array.fill(width)(new Cell("something")))
```

Comment: This is nicer than fromFunction, but it requires scala 2.8. Note that you can just use the two-dimensional version of fill: `Array.fill(height, width)(new Cell("something"))`.

Answer (score 19):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.r21376-b20100408020204 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_18).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val (height, width) = (10,20)
height: Int = 10
width: Int = 20

scala> val array = Array.fill(height, width){ new Cell("x") }
array: Array[Array[Cell[java.lang.String]]] = Array(Array(Cell(x), Cell(x), ...
scala>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
val array = Array.fromFunction((_,_) => new Cell("something"))(height, width)
```

Array.fromFunction accepts a function which takes n integer arguments and returns the element for the position in the array described by those arguments (i.e. f(x,y) should return the element for array(x)(y)) and then n integers describing the dimensions of the array in a separate argument list.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the array has already been created, you can use this:

```
for {
  i <- array.indices
  j <- array(i).indices
} array(i)(j) = new Cell("something")
```

If you can initialize at creation, see the other answers.